# Python, олимпиадный ли язык?

Tags: python

хотел поинтересоваться, к примеру я взял сайт codeforces.ru и по каждому соревнованию в сотке - точно нет тех, кто решал задания на python, за ТОП100 начинают по одному изредка появляться. С чем это связано? Частые выходы за timelimit или python не для крутых олимпиадников? Ведь на нем некоторые идеи на много легче риализовать, т.к. многое в Питоне уже есть.

Comment: Олимпиадников кто-то готовит, и этот кто-то предельно редко знает Python и очень часто Pascal. Имею мысль, что те, кто использует Python на соревнованиях, делают это по своей инициативе.

Comment: Недавно были Яндекс.Алгоритмы. Где-то в комментариях на codeforces было сказано - решение (укладывающееся в пределы) гарантированно существует для C/JAVA. Про питон и остальное - ни слова.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python отчасти является олимпиадным. На нём можно решать задачи, в которых время выполнения не будет играть существенной роли. На том же codeforces первые 2 задачи контеста вполне решаемы на python, и некоторые топы даже решают.

А в задачах, требующих сверхвысокой скорости выполнения python скорее всего не подойдёт из-за своей медлительности.

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется, суть олимпиадных задач как раз в том, чтобы реализовывать решения задач без "многого, что в Питоне уже есть", а с помощью простых циклов, математических операций и т.п.

UPD: перечитал вопрос, понял, что речь идёт не про школьные олимпиады, так что, слегка другой ответ, соответственно:
в олимпиадах, насколько я понимаю, достаточно много числодробилки. не уверен, что питон в плане скорости так же хорош в этом, как компилируемые языки. а писать сишные модули для задач, чтобы потом импортить их в питон, как-то извращенно, пожалуй, будет

Comment: ну тут скорее вступает в роль философия олимпиадника, или если ты на досуге решаешь какую-то задачу, но на соревновании, где ограничение 2 часа, разве не лучше пользоваться готовыми кирпичиками для построения своей Идеи, а не задерживаться на второстепенных вещах?

Comment: суть олимпиады как раз не в том, чтобы проще, а чтобы сложнее ;)

Comment: @actionless, во-первых, задачи на них обычно высокоуровневые (не программирование стандартных алгоритмов на скорость), а во-вторых, использование стандартных библиотек разрешено со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Comment: @eigenein,  с точки зрения здравого смысла ты прав, но когда я последний раз сталкивался близко с этим вопросом (~8-10 лет назад), нам обосновывали выбор паскаля в качестве олимпиадного языка именно его ограничениями

Comment: немного проапдейтил ответ после перепрочитывания вопроса

Comment: @actionless, более того, на олимпиадах нельзя писать модули для последующего импорта.

Comment: @DmitriyM, а инлайново в том же файле, что само задание? :)

Comment: @actionless, _сишные модули инлайново в программе на Питоне_? Или таки питоновские? Вообще разбиение олимпиадной задачи на модули редко используется. Чаще можно увидеть один-единственный `main` длинной строк эдак в 300 с невнятными названиями переменных и абсолютно непонятным смыслом. Олимпиадники редко заморачиваются такими вещами как реюзабельность и удобочитаемость их кода, ведь с ним будет работать только один человек - автор.

Answer (score 0):

Меня приглашали поучаствовать в интернет олимпиаде проводимой универом из другого города. Там список языков которые можно было использовать был достаточно обширен и включал python (даже оговаривалось, что можно использовать как 2 версию, так и 3)

Comment: Так никто и не говорит, что питон отсутствует в списке используемых языков.

Говорят про то, что в топе питон отсутствует.